# Is it possible to use Hamachi as a standalone tunnel proxy tool?

Tags: proxy, http, tunnel, hamachi

Or will i need a remote computer with internet access. This is [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/vpn.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use Hamachi as a standalone tunnel proxy tool.  You will need a remote computer with internet access.  The Hamachi servers don't act as tunnel endpoints, they simply act as the intermediaries that allow two endpoints to get connected.